# Circuit for detecting signal inversion

Tags: electromagnetism, inductive, phase

I am using two inductors on both sides of an ac carrying straight wire and want to detect their proximity from the wire. The coils are a set distance apart and move together laterally via mechanical means. As one coil moves closer to the conductor, the other moves further. See @Neil_UK illustration:

[image]

The chart below, shows the current induced in the coils as they move about the center of the conductor. Also in orange, I plotted the difference of the two signals. My problem is that the slope of the Diff A-B is to shallow between 4 and 6, where I am most interested in detecting the crossover.

[image]

To emphasis the crossover, I plotted the 1/Diff A-B in the following chart. This should give me a very sharp detection signal.

**Is this a viable strategy to sense the point where the coils cross-over? If so what would a simple circuit consist of?**

[image]

Comment: It would be great I had a quantity to indicate how off I am from the center in addition to which side.

Comment: This: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/370801/accurately-detecting-distance-from-current-carrying-wire?noredirect=1#comment895586_370801 is your previous post where you state you want an accuracy of 10 micrometers.

Comment: @oldfart. Indeed, or as close as possible. I will experiment with different ideas and see which one gives me the best result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The slope being too shallow is basically solved by "amplification" but there are techniques you can do that will significantly improve your detection. Firstly, don't run the two outer loops as shorted turns, wire them antiphase so that the net voltage signal produced is zero when placed dead centrally straddling the centre wire.

This is called an inductive balance and now you are dealing with voltages and not trying to measure currents. This technique is used in professional metal detector equipment.

Next, parallel tune the output to give you: -

- A decent voltage amplification
- A decent out-of-band noise rejection

Then amplify to give you a decent signal level. Next, use a synchronous rectifier to convert the signal to a DC level that is zero in balance, positive when pushed in one direction and negative when pushed in the other direction.

If this sounds at all familiar it's because this is how [linear variable differential transformers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_variable_differential_transformer) work: -

[image]

I would also tune the current carrying conductor to maximize current flow for the given DC power available. Again, something that is done in metal detection equipment to improve sensitivity.